# Different view edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

When I create `EditText` programmatically I have no underline (in the second `EditText`). Like this: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ut427d.jpg

When I create an `EditText` in XML everything is fine, see http://oi44.tinypic.com/nmxdnm.jpg. Where is the error?

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <include layout="@layout/input_title_layout" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/tvTitleStyle"
                    android:text="@string/diameter" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:text=":" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/diameterValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:digits="0123456780."
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And code to add `EditText` programatically:

```
final TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1f);
final TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rowParams.bottomMargin = 0;

TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
inputLinearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
TableRow tableRowEdit = new TableRow(context);

TextView titleTv = new TextView(context);
titleTv.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.tvTitleStyle);
titleTv.setText(context.getString(context.getResources().getIdentifier(inputTvs[i] , "string", context.getPackageName())));

TextView separatorTv = new TextView(context);
separatorTv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
separatorTv.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
separatorTv.setText(":");
separatorTv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


EditText editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setId(i);

tableRowEdit.addView(titleTv);
tableRowEdit.addView(separatorTv);
tableRowEdit.addView(editText);

tableLayout.addView(tableRowEdit);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what the issue might be given the code you supplied.

-Have you tried setting the layout parameters of the TableRow/TextView/EditText? The TextViews might be taking up all the visible space.

-Are you sure inputLinearLayout has been inflated?

Comment: What you mean "inflated"?

Comment: Agreed, have you checked that the issue isn't just a lack of space to display the bottom EditText in it's entirety?

Comment: I add new LinearLayout:LinearLayout testLayout = (LinearLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.testLay);
  EditText editText2 = new EditText(context);
  editText2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  testLayout.addView(editText2);
  
  EditText editText3 = new EditText(context);
  
  editText3.setWidth(50);
  testLayout.addView(editText3);

Comment: What I mean is that views aren't show automatically when you create them. At some point you should have a call like this: setContentView(inputLinearLayout);